# How to check duplicate rows in a csv file php

Tags: php, csv

I have a Csv that consists many fields ,so my problem is i want to check weather a combination of field data already exist  for eg.
fields like start_date, end date, zone,package,union should not have same data in csv
i m implementing it in cake php 4
[Screen shot of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj4M4.jpg)

i m checking the data using in_array sometimes it work if data is randomly distributed but if data is in squence it throws the message that it exist in file when in actual data is not duplicate

```
    public function validateWagerows($tmp_filename) {

        $invalid_rows = array();
        $invalid_row_count =array();
        $invalid_row_count = 0;
        $not_found_count = 0;
        $unionnumbers=array();
        $sd=array();
        $ed=array();
        $pck=array();
        $zd=array();
        $wr=array();
        $not_found=array();
        // open the file
        $file = fopen($tmp_filename, "r");
        if($file === false) {

            $this->Flash->error('Failed to open .csv file');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'upload']);
        } else {
            $header = fgetcsv($file);

            while(($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

                foreach ($header as $k => $head) {
                        if($head == 'Start Date') {
                            $start_dates = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                        }
                        else if($head == 'End Date') {
                            $end_dates = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                        }
                        else if($head == 'Local Union') {
                            $local_union_ids= (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                        }
                        else if($head == 'Package') {
                            $package_id = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                        }

                       else if($head === 'Zone') {
                            $zones_id = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';

                        }

            }

            if (in_array($start_dates,$sd) && in_array($end_dates,$ed) && in_array($local_union_ids, $unionnumbers)  && in_array($zones_id,$zd) &&  in_array($package_id,$pck)  )
            {

              $invalid_rows[$invalid_row_count]['same-data'] = "No Two or more rows with same Zone + Package +Unions within a Start and End Date can Exist in Csv ";
              $result = ['invalid_row_count' => $invalid_row_count, 'invalid_rows' => $invalid_rows];
                    $true=$true+1;
             }
          $unionnumbers[]=$local_union_ids;
          $sd[]=$start_dates;
          $ed[]=$end_dates;
          $pck[]=$package_id;
          $zd[]=$zones_id;


          $invalid_row_count++;

        }

        fclose($file);
        $result = ['invalid_row_count' => $invalid_row_count, 'invalid_rows' => $invalid_rows];
        print_r($result);
        die;
         return $result;

    }
}
```

it would be great help in figuring out it or any one having existing script can share

Comment: An efficient way to find duplicate records is to sort them and search for matching adjacent  pairs.

Comment: You're adding your `$start_dates`, `$end_dates`, `$local_union_ids`, `$package_id` and `$zones_id` to your arrays whether they are set or not. Next time you get a blank one, the blank value will already be in the array, and it'll think it's a duplicate.

Comment: Also, you're incrementing `$invalid_row_count` every time through the loop, not only when you have an invalid row.

Comment: @GregSchmidt what would be the correct approach for it

Comment: Don't add them to the duplicate-checking array if they're blank? Or use @RobRuchte's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A commonly used strategy for identifying duplicate records is [hashing](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Hashing). You can create an encoded representation of the set of values that you want to uniquely identify, and simply store those hashes in a buffer, then check to see if the hash of the current record is already in the buffer. This simplifies the logic and can be more efficient then other methods.

```php
<?php

class Test
{
    public function validateWagerows($tmp_filename)
    {
        $invalid_rows = array();
        $invalid_row_count = 0;

        $hashes = array();

        // open the file
        $file = fopen($tmp_filename, "r");
        if ($file === false)
        {

            $this->Flash->error('Failed to open .csv file');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'upload']);
        }
        else
        {
            $header = fgetcsv($file);

            while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

                foreach ($header as $k => $head) {
                    if ($head == 'Start Date') {
                        $start_dates = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                    } else if ($head == 'End Date') {
                        $end_dates = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                    } else if ($head == 'Local Union') {
                        $local_union_ids = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                    } else if ($head == 'Package') {
                        $package_id = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                    } else if ($head === 'Zone') {
                        $zones_id = (isset($row[$k])) ? trim($row[$k]) : '';
                    }
                }

                // Create a hash from the relavant values
                $currKey = sha1($start_dates . $end_dates . $local_union_ids . $zones_id . $package_id);

                // Check if the hash has already been recorded
                if (in_array($currKey, $hashes))
                {
                    $invalid_rows[$invalid_row_count]['same-data'] = "No Two or more rows with same Zone + Package +Unions within a Start and End Date can Exist in Csv ";
                }

                // Set the hash into the hash buffer
                $hashes[] = $currKey;

                // Are we doing this so we know which rows are bad? Maybe not needed...
                $invalid_row_count++;
            }

            fclose($file);
            $result = ['invalid_row_count' => $invalid_row_count, 'invalid_rows' => $invalid_rows];

            return $result;
        }
    }
}

// Create a file with some test data
$fileName = 'test.csv';
$fh = fopen($fileName, 'w+');
$testData = [
    ['Start Date', 'End Date', 'Local Union', 'Package', 'Zone'],
    ['2023-01-01', '2023-12-31', '556', '45', '15'],
    ['2023-02-01', '2024-02-01', '762', '51', '47'],
    ['2023-03-01', '2024-03-01', '545', '39', '74'],
    ['2023-02-01', '2024-02-01', '762', '51', '47'] // Duplicate in fourth row
];

foreach ($testData as $currRow) {
    fputcsv($fh, $currRow);
}

// Run the test
$test = new Test();
$result = $test->validateWagerows($fileName);

// Make sure we caught the last row
if(!array_key_exists(3, $result['invalid_rows']))
{
    echo 'The fourth row should have been flagged'.PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($result);
```